# Best way to avoid specific values, when extracting from database?

Tags: php, medoo

### The Problem

Ignoring specific values, when arrays are pulled, using medoo, and merged.

### The Details

Say I have two arrays, created from two similar tables. They have a 'user'-row and an 'id'-row.
Example below:

```
id        name   
-------   ---------
  1         John Doe     
  2         John Snow    
  3         Jane     
  4         Jane
```

What is the best way to ignore all entries that have 'John ...' in the name row?
My array_merge is currently like this:

```
  public function getUsersByName($name)
    {
        $res = array_merge(
            $this->_db->select('users1', ['id', 'name'],
            $this->_db->select('users2', ['id', 'name']
        );
        return $res;
    }
```

This returns a nice array, with all values in the tables. What is the best practice to ignore those values, and skip to the next legitimate value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run queries with `WHERE .. NOT LIKE ..` in medoo, you can pass a third parameter to `select()` that contains an array of the where clauses. The key is the column with the operator, and the value is - well, the value.

For example, to select from `users1` where no names begin with `John`, you'll need

```php
$this->_db->select('users1', ['id', 'name'], ['name[!~]' => 'John']);
```

The `[!~]` signalizes `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: Thank you Qirel, I can confirm that this has the desired effect of excluding certain calues.

Comment: ['name[!~]' => 'John'] is equivalent to name NOT LIKE "%John%". Use ['name[!~]' => 'John%'] if you only want to exclude name starting with John, also is faster (equivalent to name NOT LIKE "John%").